# Overwrite sheets saving and the other sheets on excel

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, openpyxl, openxml

i made a script that compare datas form diferent sheets, all godd, now i want to add this updates sheet instead of the old one on the entire excel and keeping the other sheets.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from timestampdirectory import  createdir
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl import worksheet
import os
import time
def svnanalysis():

    dest = createdir()
    dfSvnUsers = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnUsers.xlsx"))
    dfSvnGroupMembership = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnGroupMembership.xlsx"))
    dfSvnRepoGroupAccess = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "SvnRepoGroupAccess.xlsx"))
    dfsvnReposSize = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "svnReposSize.xlsx"))
    dfsvnRepoLastChangeDate = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest, "svnRepoLastChangeDate.xlsx"))
    dfUserDetails = pd.read_excel(r"D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\CM_UsersDetails.xlsx")

    timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-")
    xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(dest,f'{timestr}Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx'))

    dfUserDetails.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='UserDetails',index = False)
    dfSvnUsers.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnUsers', index = False )
    dfSvnGroupMembership.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnGroupMembership', index = False )
    dfSvnRepoGroupAccess.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnRepoGroupAccess', index = False)
    dfsvnReposSize.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='svnReposSize', index = False)
    dfsvnRepoLastChangeDate.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='svnRepoLastChangeDate',index= False)
    xlwriter.close()
```

whats above its in the same script where i used some xlsx files an create only 1 xlsx with those files as sheets, now below i make some changes in SvnUser sheet and i want to upload it on the excel instead of old sheet SvnUser, and keep the other sheets

```
   # xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(dest, f'{timestr}Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx'))
    svnUsers = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,f'{timestr}Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx'), sheet_name="SvnUsers")
    details = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(dest,f'{timestr}Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx'), sheet_name="UserDetails")
    svnUsers = svnUsers.assign(SVNaccount=svnUsers["accountName"].isin(details["Account"]).astype(bool))

    print(svnUsers)
   # dfSvnUsers.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name='SvnUsers', index = False )

   # xlwriter.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve that would be to overwrite the entire excel sheet, for example like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe from excel file
df = pd.read_excel(
    '2022-06-15-Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx',
    engine='openpyxl',
    sheet_name='UserDetails'
)
res_df = ..... # calculate the df you want to write
# overwrite excel sheet with dataframe
with pd.ExcelWriter(
    '2022-06-15-Usage-SvnAnalysis.xlsx',
    engine='openpyxl',
    mode='a',
    if_sheet_exists='replace'
) as writer:
    res_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='UserDetails')
```